# setting up vim fireplace, linking clojure code

Tags: vim, clojure, text-editor, vim-plugin

I just installed VIM and a few plugins, one of which is vim fireplace. A problem I have is that fireplace can't find my clojure code. I put my clojure code under vimfiles/bundle (I'm running windows).

I followed these instructions:

http://kevinmccarthy.org/blog/2013/10/12/setting-up-vim-for-clojure/

When I run a sample clojure function in the command line (which I get to using cqc), I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>20_inputeval... foreplay#echo_session_eval..foreplay#session_eval...<SNR>20_eval...6:
line 38
E605: Exception not caught: Error running clojure:Error:Could not find or load main class clojure.main^@
Error detected while processing function <SNR>20_inputeval:
line 4
E71:missing :endif
```

Here is my .vimrc:

```
set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin

syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
execute pathogen#infect()
set nobackup
set nowritebackup

set diffexpr=MyDiff()
function MyDiff()
  let opt = '-a --binary '
  if &diffopt =~ 'icase' | let opt = opt . '-i ' | endif
  if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt = opt . '-b ' | endif
  let arg1 = v:fname_in
  if arg1 =~ ' ' | let arg1 = '"' . arg1 . '"' | endif
  let arg2 = v:fname_new
  if arg2 =~ ' ' | let arg2 = '"' . arg2 . '"' | endif
  let arg3 = v:fname_out
  if arg3 =~ ' ' | let arg3 = '"' . arg3 . '"' | endif
  let eq = ''
  if $VIMRUNTIME =~ ' '
    if &sh =~ '\<cmd'
      let cmd = '""' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
      let eq = '"'
    else
      let cmd = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff"'
    endif
  else
    let cmd = $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff'
  endif
  silent execute '!' . cmd . ' ' . opt . arg1 . ' ' . arg2 . ' > ' . arg3 . eq
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

fireplace is not able to set classpath which may be because you are not working with a lein project. But that is not a requirement, you can always connect to a running nrepl ( which can be launched via `lein repl`) and connect to it from vim using `:Connect nrepl://localhost:port`.

Comment: I get the same error when I type "lein nrep". Also, i'm not able to determine my port because of security restrictions on my computer.

Comment: please try "lein repl" pay attention its REPL not NREPL. Also the port is printed when repl is launched.

Comment: I tried "lein repl" but get the same error. earlier you wrote "lein nrep", that's why i tried that.